# easeljs create painting tools updateCache('destination-out')

Tags: easeljs

I am working on a painting tools with eraser.

I don't know why when i click eraser and start to clear up. 
The whole stage will become lighter.After i set updateCache('destination-out').

```
wrapper.addEventListener("pressup", function(event) {
              console.log("up");
              dragging = false;


              // real_wrapper.updateCache();

              if (erase == true) {
                  drawStroke(real_draw);
                  real_wrapper.updateCache('destination-out');

              } else {
                  drawStroke(real_draw);
                  real_wrapper.updateCache();
                  tmp_draw.graphics.clear();
                  wrapper.updateCache();
              }

              ppts = [];
          });
```

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/steven_wong/mnfupy5o/6/
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your graphics between draws. Right now your code is redrawing all of the old strokes each time, so when you're using the pencil, all the old shapes are made darker, when you're using the eraser, they become lighter.

```
graphics.clear();
```

Here's a fixed version:
https://jsfiddle.net/mnfupy5o/7/